# Getting total percentage inside while loop

Tags: php, mysql

For example I have a mysql_num_rows results of 4,8,15,16,23,42 in a query that is inside a while loop of another query. My question is how can I get the percentage per each result of mysql_num_rows inside my while loop? Example: 4,8,15,16,23,42. Total is 108. $sum = 108. Percentage of 4 = 4/$sum = 3.7%, 8 = 8/$sum = 7.4% and so on..

Comment: If you posted your code, I'd bet you would get an answer with code, which might be useful. :-)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding up total of mysql_num_rows in a while loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7788910/adding-up-total-of-mysql-num-rows-in-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can store all the values in an array and do the calcs after you have retrieved the data from the database

eg

```
$datastore = array();
$total = 0;

while(list($amount) = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
    $datastore[] = $amount;
    $total += $amount;
}

foreach ($datastore as $amount) {
  echo $amount," - ";
  printf("%5.2f", $amount/$total);
  echo "\r\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$values = array(4, 8, 15, ...);

$sum = array_sum($values);

foreach($values as $value) {
    echo ($value / $sum) * 100;
}
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.org/6WOfIeMH).

Answer (score 0):

So you are saying that you want the $sum before the individual results right? You could do a simple additional query to get the sum before you pull out the individual results. Use the [SUM](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) aggregate function. It is probably also possible to get the percentage in your SQL results. That would mean a slightly more complex query, but not an additional query.